# Robocopy copied Delta files to another location

Tags: robocopy

robocopy is a great tool for making full/incremental copies and I like to use it for Backups.
One thing, I still haven´t figured out: How to treat the Delta files specifically

Situation:
**Source A** is being copied to **Destination B**. Either with switch /MIR or at least with /E

Example

*robocopy "E:\A" "\\servername\e$\B" /E /B /R:1 /W:1 /Copyall*

Normally, only differential files (Delta) are being copied.

So what if I want to script to compress the newly copied files to an archiv for different purposes? Or If I want to move/copy them to location D ?

So in my opinion, a 3rd location in the Script would be nice

robocopy Source A ; match it with Source B and then copy the Delta to location D
within a script we then could compress it

The only thing I can think of is to set the archive bit or check the timestamp, but this is not a very solid solution in my opinion

Is it possible to handle that with robocopy or a script?

Comment: You could use the "/L" and "/log" switch to get a list of those "Delta" files and than use a batch script with a For to copy those delta files to any locaction you want...

Comment: Thanks - so something like that?
https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/f7elvz/scripted_file_copy_ideas_requested/fio38cj/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Comment: I guess, don't know powershell very well. I would try it in batch since my powershell knowledge is not very good.

Comment: Maybe I post a sample script later. How would you like to compress the delta Files? *.zip *.rar *.7z

Comment: thanks, Ricardo!
the Powershell Script handling I can do myself, if I know the way to go. Plain .zip will do. If not, I can add a 7z as well

Answer (score 1):

You could use a batch script like this just change the variable values with your own needs:

```
@echo off
:: This line asks for admin permission since the robocopy /b /copyall requires admin permission
net session >nul 2>&1 || (powershell start -verb runas '"%~0"' &exit /b)

:: Put Source Folder here
set Source=W:\md\Musicas

:: Put Comparison Folder here:
set Comparison=%userprofile%\desktop\Comparison

:: Put Destination of Delta Files Here:
set DeltaFiles=%userprofile%\desktop\Delta

:: Put the path to the log file here
set LogFile=%userprofile%\desktop\Filelist.txt

:: Put the path to command line 7zip version here:
set seven=C:\Program Files\CLI\7zip\7za.exe

:: This graps the files that exist in the original folders but don't exist in the comparision folder and saves them in the logfile
robocopy "%Source%" "%Comparison%" /L /NJH /NJS /NC /NS /NDL /E /R:1 /W:1 /Log:"%LogFile%"

:: This copies the files in the logfile to the delta folder:
For /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%LogFile%") do Robocopy "%Source%" "%DeltaFiles%" "%%~nxa" /B /ndl /copyall /s /NJS /NJH /R:1 /w:1

:: This uses 7zip to put the delta folder into a zip file and delete the Delta folder (if you don't want to delete remove -sdel)
"%seven%" a -tzip -r -sdel "%~dp0delta.zip" "%DeltaFiles%"

:: As an Alternative you could use powershell instead of 7zip to create the zip file:
::Powershell Compress-Archive -Path "%DeltaFiles%" -DestinationPath "%DeltaFiles%\Delta.zip"

exit
```

[image]